# How to give fake GPU info to site

Tags: javascript, webgl, cefsharp

I need to create web browser using CefSharp.Wpf with ability to give fake data to site for example CPU cores, browser plugins, platform name etc. 
There are site that can retrieve all this info: https://www.deviceinfo.me/

My quesiton is: How to hide GPU info from this site? Using javascript or CefSharp functionality

I have tried to redefine WebGLRenderingContext.getParameter method, which gives an info about GPU renderer and vendor:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

var gl;

try {
  gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2") || canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl2") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
} catch (e) {
}

var oldParam = WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getParameter;


WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getParameter = function(parameter){

    console.log("we have guests");

    if(parameter == debugInfo.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL){
         return "GTX 1080";
    }

    if(parameter == gl.getExtension("WEBGL_debug_renderer_info").UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL){
        return "GTX 1080";
    }

    if(parameter == debugInfo.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL){
        return "NVidia";
    }

    if(parameter == gl.VERSION){
        return "GTX 1080";
    }
    return oldParam(parameter);
};
```

I expected to completely redefine this method and return some fake info, but when i called `gl.getParameter(param)` again, it still gave me an old gpu info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still want Canvas2D and WebGL to still work then you can't hide since they can finger print by actually rendering.

You could disable them with

```
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function() {
  return null;
};
```

Though the fact they don't exist is also a data point.

Otherwise your wrapper appears to have some issues.

First you really should set the function **before** creating the context.

Second your last line should be

```
   oldParam.call(this, parameter);
```

Also you didn't show `debugInfo` but you can use `WebGLRenderingContext` instead or you can just hard code the numbers

As for http://www.deviceinfo.me you need to make sure your patch runs in all iframes and workers before any other JavaScript.

```js
WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getParameter = function(origFn) {
  const paramMap = {};
  paramMap[0x9245] = "Foo";         // UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL
  paramMap[0x9246] = "Bar";         // UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL
  paramMap[0x1F00] = "Nobody";      // VENDOR
  paramMap[0x1F01] = "Jim";         // RENDERER
  paramMap[0x1F02] = "Version 1.0"; // VERSION

  return function(parameter) {
    return paramMap[parameter] || origFn.call(this, parameter);
  };
}(WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getParameter);

// --- test

const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const ext = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_debug_renderer_info');

show(gl, gl, [
  'VENDOR',
  'RENDERER',
  'VERSION',
]);
if (ext) {
  show(gl, ext, [
    'UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL',
    'UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL',
  ]);
}

function show(gl, base, params) {
  for (const param of params) {
    console.log(param, ':', gl.getParameter(base[param]));
  }
}
```

Comment: These modification is detectable. https://abrahamjuliot.github.io/creepjs/ :

        WebGLRenderingContext.getParameter:
        - failed class extends error
        - failed toString
        - failed "prototype" in function
        - failed descriptor
        - failed own property
        - failed descriptor keys
        - failed own property names
        - failed own keys names
        - failed at incompatible proxy error

Comment: Yes, what's your point? That wasn't part of the question and as pointed out in this answer, your only real option is to disable the API.

Comment: I don't think so, I think changing it in JS is detectable, but it can be done undetected with `puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth`. But it will still be exposed inside workers though. Also, I don't think fingerprinting will give the exact model of GPU, it's probably more broad. Additionally, you can fake canvas fingerprinting too with https://wiki.bablosoft.com/doku.php?id=perfectcanvas

Comment: That solution [doesn't handle WebGL](https://wiki.bablosoft.com/doku.php?id=perfectcanvas#webgl_is_not_implemented_yet) so you're back to "disable the API"

Answer (score 1):

There is `WebGLRenderingContext` and `WebGL2RenderingContext`

Comment: I tried to use them, but I don't know how to make them give fake information about GPU

Comment: The way you implemented it works just fine if you either: shadow the `getParameter` method of  **`WebGL2RenderingContext`** or request a `"webgl"` 1 context.